# When designing my database schema in SQLAlchemy, how often do I need to use "backrefs"?

Tags: mysql, database, orm, schema, sqlalchemy

I come from the Django world and never had "backrefs".  All I did was define the ForeignKey.

That's it.

Why would I use backref for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For understand backref please check the given example

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import Table, Text

engine = create_engine('mysql://root:ababab@localhost/alctest',
            echo=False)

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String(100))
    fullname = Column(String(100))
    password = Column(String(100))

    def __init__(self, name, fullname, password):
        self.name = name
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.password = password

        def __repr__(self):
        return "<User('%s','%s', '%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.password)


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    email_address = Column(String(100), nullable=False)

    #foreign key, must define relationship
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = relationship("User", backref = backref('addresses',order_by=id))
```

This is very simple example. Now if you want to access the `user` of the `addresses` then you can directly get from `user_id` attribute if `addresses` model. This will return you the `id` of the `user`.

If you want the object of the `user` which is associated with this `addresses` then you have to use [`get()`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get) method with `user_id`.

Now in reverse case if you want to access `addresses` of the `user` then you have to run query like

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE user_id = $1
```

But if you will use `backref` then sqlalchemy will run this query when you access that attribute.

Now in our example there if you will access `userobject.addresses` then it will run the query

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE user_id = userobject.id
```

***There is no attribute like `addresses` in `User` model this will be set by `backref` from `Address` model's `user` attribute.***